# Get all rows from a dataframe, which have matching values from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, querying

I have two data frames, take the example below

df1

```
userid| name  
    33|  Paul   
    2 |  jack   
    32|  Ryan
```

df2

```
userid| sport | song 
79 |  tennis  | lovelies  
33 |  swimmin | Beatles  
21 |  boxing  | stones
```

how would I get a df3, where if the userids match between df1, and df2, I want to df3 to contain only those rows from df2 where they matched with df1

*I don't think a JOIN is the answer here, because I want ONLY the rows from df2. not the rows from df1.*

Thanks!

Comment: Its a dupe, you are looking for merge

Comment: it's more like a `isin` no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pandas.Series.isin`

```
df2[df2['userid'].isin(df1['userid'])]
```

#### output

```
   userid      sport        song 
1      33    swimmin    Beatles
```

Comment: I don't want the name from df1. I just want all the rows from df2.

Comment: thanks a lot this helps a lot. just a clarification, if I have user ids in 2 different columns in df1, would df2[df2['userid'].isin(df1['userid1']).isin(df1['userid2']) work?

Comment: it all depends on what you want, you're doing an `and` operation there, if you want that, then that code is correct

Comment: this answer didn't actually work for me, since it only made more columns, I dint get a data frame. the resulting data frame had 0 rows, and matching values were made as columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181100/discussion-between-yuca-and-steelfox).